# How to do multiple integrations?

Tags: numerical-integration

I want to do the following multiple integrations numerically

$\int_{a}^{b} dx \left[~f(x){\int_{a}^{b} g(x,y_1)dy_1\over \int_{a}^{b} h(x,y_2)dy_2}\right]$

where $a,b$ are some numbers.

I tried

```
NIntegrate[f[x] NIntegrate[g[x,y1],{y1,a,b}](NIntegrate[h[x,y2],{y2,a,b}])^{-1},{x,a,b}]
```

However, Mathematica says "the integrand has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points ...."

Could anyone help me with this?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should supply the definitions of `f[x]`, `g[x,y]` and `h[x,y`]. Also needed are the numerical limits `a` and `b`. Without these, it is difficult to help.

Comment: `f(x)` is not equivlent to `f[x]`, which is what was wanted.

Comment: Thank you very much Jack for resolving the issue! I really appreciate your detail Answer.

Comment: Thank you Daniel! That was my typo and I fixed it.

Comment: @Shu:  If you find that an answer solves your problem, you should click the check box next to it;  that way, the answer is marked as "accepted" and the answerer gets a reputation bonus.

Answer (score 3):

I will make up some simple functions to try to illustrate the point.

```
f[x_] := (x + 1)
g[x_, y_] := x^2 + y
h[x_, y_] := y^2 + x
```

Then try

```
NIntegrate[f[x] NIntegrate[g[x, y], {y, 1, 2}]/
   NIntegrate[h[x, y], {y, 1, 2}], {x, 1, 2}]
```

errors are generated and there is no output.

In order to determine the correct answer (for later validation) I will use Integrate.

```
f[x] Integrate[g[x, y], {y, a, b}]/Integrate[h[x, y], {y, a, b}]

(* ((1 + x) (-(a^2/2) + b^2/2 + (-a + b) x^2))/
 (-(a^3/3) + b^3/3 + (-a + b) x) *)
```

Let's integrate this expression from 1 to 2. We define a function that represents the expression above.

```
fgh[x_, a_, b_] := ((1 + x) (-(a^2/2) + b^2/2 + (-a + b) x^2))/
                   (-(a^3/3) + b^3/3 + (-a + b) x)

Integrate[fgh[x, 1, 2], {x, 1, 2}] // N

(* 2.51515 *)
```

The answer is 2.51515.

Clear everything and start over

```
Remove["Global`*"]
```

We will redefine the functions and put a qualifier on the input arguments so that they must be numeric. This is probably the key point as to why you are experiencing problems.

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := (x + 1)
g[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := x^2 + y
h[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := y^2 + x
```

Now when we execute `NIntegrate` we get the correct answer although we still have some warning messages.

```
NIntegrate[f[x] NIntegrate[g[x, y], {y, 1, 2}]/
                NIntegrate[h[x, y], {y, 1, 2}], {x, 1, 2}]


(* 2.51515 *)
```

In order to get rid of the annoying error messages, define a new function which is equal to the integrand.

```
fgh[x_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] := 
 f[x] NIntegrate[g[x, y], {y, a, b}]/NIntegrate[h[x, y], {y, a, b}]
```

Now when it is numerically integrated we get the same (correct) answer but without any warnings.

```
 NIntegrate[fgh[x, 1, 2], {x, 1, 2}]

(* 2.51515 *)
```

I am unable to explain why error messages are generated for the first integration using

```
f[x] NIntegrate[g[x, y], {y, 1, 2}]/NIntegrate[h[x, y], {y, 1, 2}]
```

but not for

```
fgh[x, 1, 2]
```

Perhaps another member can explain why. It may be related to this extract from the documentation.

***`NIntegrate` first localizes the values of all variables, then evaluates f with the variables being symbolic, and then repeatedly evaluates the result numerically.***

The good news is that both give the correct answer.